# Is Swift string count included in string storage?

Tags: swift, string, count, compiler-optimization

My app involves repeated equality comparisons of many megabytes of an array of strings.  I was (naively?) surprised that such comparisons became immensely faster when I added a shadow array of the count of each string; if the counts are not equal, the strings cannot be equal.

I would have thought that the Swift compiler could easily and efficiently maintain a string's count in the internal representation, and short-circuit string equality comparisons if the counts differ.  The initial creation of each string would provide the opportunity to initialize the count, and each manipulation would then know the count of each participant.  But it seems not so.  If only some applications would benefit from a stored count, a compiler switch to turn it on could help them.

Would this be a reasonable standard library refinement?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the compiler.

Comment: The compiler could supply the counts of string literals.

Comment: May as well cross-link the related forum post: https://forums.swift.org/t/use-string-counts-to-short-circuit-string-comparisons/53743

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `String` is that it is not stored always in the same way. There are different types of storage and for them to be properly compared, they have to be converted to the same representation first.

Looking into the source code here: [StringComparison.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f8e5f28b8632c0e3ccde9a09ce5195c5d96733eb/stdlib/public/core/StringComparison.swift), I think you are right and `count` should be compared first when checking equality.

I recommend filing a bug.

Comment: (didn't down-vote) The problem is that checking the count is itself an `O(n)` operation, so unless it's cached, counting the length is no faster than just doing the comparison.

Comment: @Alexander I think count is always stored, at least from what I saw in the source code. See `_stringCompareSlow(lhs, 0..<lhs.count, rhs, 0..<rhs.count, expecting: expecting)`